# Adding FreeRDP on a separate Swift project

Tags: swift, rdp, freerdp

I've run the control https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP successfully and everything works fine on the same project.

I need to use it on new Swift project, I've been trying for couple of days with no luck. always getting plenty of errors.

Also is it possible to create a framework from the FreeRDP project that can be used on my swift project to be able to connect to an RDP instance?

Comment: How did you even import OpenSSL with ios 11>? When i try to create project, i get errors says that "warning: iOS 11.3.0 does not support armv7,
warning: iOS 11.3.0 does not support armv7s"  and if i remove armv7 and armv7s i get lots of errors in project about unknown platform and frameworks.